# Custom database table query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So, I created a custom wp database table (called `"wp_my_table"`).

I can create a new row or upload values to the table just fine.

But I am new to how to get the values out of the table.

Below is a general database structure:

[image]

Each row gets its own `ID` and also has `post_id` which is associated with other posts (In this example, there are three different `post_id`: 433, 6554, 23)

For a query search, I want to be able to search rows with specific `post_id` in a descent order:

For example:

1. Look for `post_id` of `"433"`
2. Get first 2 rows (order by descent date): `id=1, 3` are selected
3. Get other info such as `contents`

Let say, there is a `load more` button to load the next set of data (in this case, it will be `id=4, 8`).

How does it know which row is the next set of data and how do I pull it out?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. I am more interested in php side as I got js part figured out.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can create triggers in mysql to make this data management.
Not sure if the wordpress will do this, then you have to develop on the side php or mysql (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to use

`$wpdb->get_result('sql query');` method

Read this

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Your query will be something like this:
It's not a tested code, just assumption

You need to use

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT ID, post_id, contents, date  
    FROM wp_my_table
    WHERE post_id = 433 
    date DESC
    LIMIT startRow, howManyRows"
);

foreach ($rows as $row) 
{
    echo $row->post_id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was researching for about 1 hour and this will certainly help! =)